# Selenium dhtmlxtree NoSuchElementException in Chrome Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, dhtmlx

I could reach all elements by `driver.findElement()` function.
**Tree elements were created using dhtmlx library and when I try to reach them I get NoSuchElementException**.

I tried to reach by id, xpath, class, text, etc. but none of them worked for me. I also tried implicit waiting and `Thread.sleep()` methods but the result is the same.

```
 > <tr> <td class="standartTreeImage"> <img border="0" align="absmiddle"
    > style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 18px; height: 18px;"
    > src="http://marduk:5543/atlas/themes/third_party/dhtmlx/dhtmlxTree/codebase/imgs/vse_datasources/plus3.gif">
    > </td> <td width="20px" style="display: none;"> <img align="absmiddle"
    > src="http://marduk:5543/atlas/themes/third_party/dhtmlx/dhtmlxTree/codebase/imgs/vse_datasources/iconUncheckAll.gif"
    > style="width: 16px; height: 16px;"> </td> <td
    > class="standartTreeImage" style="width: 18px;"> <img border="0"
    > align="absmiddle" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 18px;
    > height: 18px;"
    > src="http://marduk:5543/atlas/themes/third_party/dhtmlx/dhtmlxTree/codebase/imgs/vse_datasources/folderClosed.gif">
    > </td> <td class="standartTreeRow" nowrap="" style="width: 100%;
    > font-size: 10pt; cursor: pointer;"> <span class="standartTreeRow"
    > style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">hr-istanbul [15]</span>
    > </td> </tr>
```

For example one of them is this: I need to click the first `td`. Only locator is the image but I can not access the element .. NoSuchElementException.

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://marduk:5543/atlas/themes/third_party/dhtmlx/dhtmlxTree/codebase/imgs/vse_datasources/plus3.gif')]"));
```

Also tried to reach last column element it didnt work either.

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'hr-istanbul [15]')]"));
```

Comment: can there be more than one element with same id?

Comment: share your html and java code

Comment: Some of them even dont contain any id but they got unique text field etc. to locate them . I can't share as I mentioned , will try to share part of them

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting `NoSuchElementException` as your provided exception, There may be following reasons :-

- May be you are locating with incorrect locator, So you need to share HTML for better locator solution.
- May be when you are going to find element, it would not be present on the `DOM`, So you should implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until element visible as below :-

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(byObject));
  ```
- May be this element is inside any `frame` or `iframe`. If it is, you need to switch that `frame` or `iframe` before finding the element as below :-

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

  //Find frame or iframe and switch
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("your frame id or name"));

  //Now find the element 
  WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(byObject));

  //Once all your stuff done with this frame need to switch back to default
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  ```

Comment: Thanks for advice. I shared the html. I tried your solution but doesn't work. It is also not inside iframe

Comment: You are trying to locate `minus3.gif` while in your provided HTML it shows `plus3.gif`???? I think you need to correct your locator..:)

Comment: Sorry my bad .. the problem is independent from it. I edited but nothing changed . Also edited the question

Comment: Did you tried to locate `td` instead as `By.className("standartTreeImage")`??